# Probability of at least $k$ events in terms of probability of exactly $k$ and exactly $k+1$ events

Tags: probability

(Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Nwang, p.38)
[image]

Can anybody give me a hint? I have no idea how it should be possbile without knowing the probability of either the 'left' or the 'right' part of the other exact events, e.g. $C_{k+2}, ..., C_{n}$.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it meant to ask for $C_k$ in terms of $B_k$ and $B_{k+1}$?

Comment: Good thought, that might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to do this, because for $0 < k < n - 1$ you could have $P(C_k) = 0$ and $P(C_{k+1}) = 0$ but $P(B_k)$ either $0$ (e.g. if with probabilty $1$ none of the events occur) or $1$ (e.g. if with probability $1$ all the events will occur), or anything in between.

Comment: Of course, this makes sense. Anyway, I rather questioned myself that the exercise ;)